# Point Cloud Library Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++11, iteration, cloud, point, closest

i'm trying to do an iterative closest point but since I'm a noob I'm trying starting from this tutorial:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php

all required dependencies are installed, Operative System is MacOs High Sierra, I have this error when I execute make command :

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ, flann::L2_Simple<float> >::setInputCloud(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const> const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ, flann::L2_Simple<float> > in iterative_closest_point.cpp.o
  "pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ, flann::L2_Simple<float> >::radiusSearch(pcl::PointXYZ const&, double, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&, std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&, unsigned int) const", referenced from:
      vtable for pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ, flann::L2_Simple<float> > in iterative_closest_point.cpp.o
  "pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ, flann::L2_Simple<float> >::nearestKSearch(pcl::PointXYZ const&, int, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&, std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >&) const", referenced from:
      vtable for pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ, flann::L2_Simple<float> > in iterative_closest_point.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [iterative_closest_point] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/iterative_closest_point.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

I can not understand what I'm wrong